# socket-over-ssh factory

Tags: java, sockets, ssh, factory

I would like to use some JMS (Java Message Service) library, ActiveMQ or FFMQ, but need to run it over SSH protocol. I have started implementing my own connection factory method of ActiveMQ, but then the idea of implementing Socket/SocketFactory interfaces over SSH has struck me. It would let me adapt pretty much any JMS implementation without really touching its code. As usual, somebody has already had this idea and I have found couple implementations of this approach.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/lib-src/shock/org/apache/pig/shock/SSHSocketImplFactory.java
http://benkstein.net/java/SSHSocketFactory/javadoc/

The first one is a class somewhere in the guts of Apache Pig. The second is a hack/addon for MySQL client, published by Frank Benkstein in 2004. It appears that MySQL community was not interested in it (http://www.webservertalk.com/archive277-2004-7-294282.html).

I wonder if there are other implementations of SocketOverSsh factory, possibly better documented/supported?

Update: My primary motivation is to avoid having additional open ports or configuration changes both on the client and the server. So SOCKS or plain port forwarding are not desirable solutions.

Answer (score 2):

This looks a bit heavy-weight. Have you considered finding a solution using the SOCKS protocol? An ssh-client can act as a SOCKS proxy by e.g. invoking it with "ssh -D ". The good thing is that the [JVM already knows how to use SOCKS](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) automatically for network connections. Of course the cave-at is that the ssh-connection would be established outside of the Java app.

Comment: Yes, this could be an option. OpenSSH client even can simulate SOCKS over SSH. However, my primary motivation is to avoid additional ports or configuration changes both on the client and the server. So for this particular application I will not go for SOCKS. Thanks for the feedback anyway.

Comment: Why make SSH a detail of your implementation? Why not build a persistent tunnel with OpenSSH externally and treat the broker as a standard host?

Comment: I would like to do it for the same reason people make SSL "a detail" of an implementation: make it more user friendly and robust. The application will be used to execute remote commands on Internet hosts and SSH will be there as a rule.